# I am trying to pull the app data from my phone to my pc but it says the path does not exist?

Tags: adb

I have installed adb and am trying to pull the app data from an app. However, the adb command does not recognize the path. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong here? I have attached the path and the message that the cmd relays as I run the command.
[image: This is the path that I am trying to import.]

[image: This is what the cmd relays as I run the command.]

Comment: `adb pull /sdcard/Pictures/Cats` or `adb pull /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Cats`

Comment: @Irfan Latif Thank you good sir.

Comment: @AliMustafa And next time please don't post the console output in a screen shot. You can simply copy and paste the content to get it as text and the paste it into the question and format it as code.

Comment: @Robert Thank you. I will keep that in mind next time.